# Matlab changing to function

Tags: matlab, function

So basically I know the coding but I don't understand why it doesn't run. I have begun studying function and I am trying to run this code example out the book but it doesn't allow me when I paste it unto MATLAB just like this, I don't know why. I looked through the MATLAB website but their examples are quite hard to follow, maybe I just don't see it.

```
function Exercise5_20
tto = fzero(@Tto, [0.2 0.9])

function t = Tto(x)
t = Thq(exp(-x*pi^2))-pi/2/sqrt(5);

function qq = Thq(q)
k = 0:10;
qq = 2*q^(1/4).*sum((-1).^k./(2*k+1).*q.^(k.*(k+1)));
```

Comment: You can't simply put all of that into the command prompt.  Put that all into a **file called `Exercise5_20`**, then type in `Exercise5_20` in the command prompt to execute the script.  Make sure the working directory is selected where you have saved this script.

Comment: So technically it is correct as it is just in put Exercise5_20 to command prompt once making a file with the same name?

Comment: I don't quite understand your first comment.  As for your second comment, the answer is yes.

Comment: No worries! I won't write an answer to this because it's pretty trivial.  Good luck!